# how to remove share permission for several dashboards to a set of users

Tags: sharing, dashboard, bulk-permission

I have five users for whom several dashboard has been shared with viewer permission. Is there any way to remove the share permission to set of users in a go for each dashboards.Please give your thoughts on this.

Comment: How were the shares created initially? Was it via sharing groups or permission sets?

Comment: Hi, I have a question can we share an access to dashboard with Viewer access to the user using the permission set? Coming to your question, a set of five users present in a public group of total count 60 users to whom the dashboard is shared with viewer access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of approaching your problem. Here are three of them which I'd suggest you consider:

1. Remove these 5 users from your public group of 60 Users. Create a new group for the 5 users where you give them the same sharing on everything you want except for the dashboards.
2. Alternatively, you could remove the sharing access on the dashboard for all 60 users from the existing group. Then, create a new group minus the 5 users you don't want to have access to the dashboards and give those users access to the dashboards via that group. Users can be members of more than one group.
3. **Better solution:** Do a combination of both 1 and 2, meaning split out the 5 users into their own group and the other 55 into another group. Combine them into a 3rd group wherever you want to provide common permissions for the two group. Finally, add only the group of 55 to a group that has permission to view the dashboard. This is a bit more complex but may simplify management of permissions for you in the future.

Sharing via groups can be additive, so you can add the users from one group to another group to combine sharing permissions. The key here is to organize your groups in a way that makes sense so you're able to add or exclude permissions from people who are members of the sub-groups in ways that are easy for you to manage. In your case, it appears that your 60 member group was too large for your needs.